# Laplace transform of integral of a function

Tags: laplace-transform

I''m currently studying Laplace transforms using the textbook *Advanced Engineering Mathematics 10e (Kreyszig)* and had a question regarding the Laplace transforms of the integral of a function.

The example in the textbook is:

> Find the inverse of $\dfrac{1}{s(s^2 + w^2)}$.

Since we know that:

$$
\begin{align}
f(t) & = \sin{(wt)} \\
\mathcal{L}(f) & = \frac{w}{s^2 + w^2}
\end{align}
$$

We also know that:

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{s^2 + w^2} \right) = \frac{1}{w} \sin{(wt)}
$$

What's confusing me is the part where we apply the integral in order to obtain the final solution. The textbook does as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{s(s^2 + w^2)} \right) & = \int_0^t \frac{1}{w}\sin{(wt)} d \tau \\
& = \frac{1}{w^2}(1 - \cos{(wt)})
\end{align}
$$

How was the last equation derived? Aren't $t$ and $w$ constants when integrating for $\tau$? Perhaps I'm missing something regarding $\tau$ but there isn't any explanation for it in the textbook.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$f(t):=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \dfrac{1}{s(s^2+w^2)}(t) \right)$$

so that

$$\dfrac{1}{s(s^2+w^2)}=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$$ and

$$\dfrac{1}{s^2+w^2}=\int_0^\infty f(t)se^{-st}dt\stackrel{\ast}{=}\int_0^\infty f^\prime(t)e^{-st}dt$$ where $\stackrel{\ast}{=}$ comes from integrating by parts, provided we justify $[f(t)e^{-st}]_0^\infty=0$.

So

$$f^\prime(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{s^2+w^2} \right) \implies f(t) = \int_0^t\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{s^2+w^2} \right) (\tau)d\tau$$

provided we also justify $f(0)=0$. The textbook's $wt$ is a misprint for $w\tau$.

Comment: You just proved $\mathcal{L}[f'(t)]=sF(s)-f(0)$, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's one thing wrong with one of your hypotheses. You actually have:

$$\mathscr{L}\left( \dfrac{1}{w}\sin(wt) \right)=\dfrac{1}{s^2+w^2}$$

and not the other way around.

The Laplace transform of a convolution of two functions is given by:

$$\mathscr{L}(f \circledast g) = \mathscr{L}(f) \mathscr{L}(g)$$

Make $f=\dfrac{1}{w}\sin(wt)$ and $g=1$ so that:
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{s(s^2 + w^2)} & = \mathscr{L}\left( \dfrac{1}{w} \sin(wt) \right) \mathscr{L}(1) \\ & =\mathscr{L}\left(1 \circledast \dfrac{1}{w}{\sin(wt)} \right) \\ 
& = \int_0^t \dfrac{1}{w}\sin(wx) 1(1-x) dx \\
& = \dfrac {1}{w^2}(1-\cos(wt))
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Sean, your proposition is really correct, but the step in the convolution with $1(t)$ is incorrect! $\mathscr{L}\left(1 \circledast \dfrac{1}{w}{\sin(wt)} \right)=\int_0^t \dfrac{1}{w}\sin(wx)dx=\dfrac {1}{w^2}(1-\cos(wt))$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess , they have applied **Convolution theorem**
Here it is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Using the fact that Laplace of 1 is $1/s$

Comment: This is quite strange though... Convolutions are in the same chapter but at a much later section.

Comment: The way they have written the solution , I don't think they are applying something other than Convolution

Comment: Yes, I agree I don't see any other way that they achieved this result. However, I really don't think it would be appropriate of the authors to suddenly use convolution operations without even having taught them yet. :(

Comment: Yeah I agree with you .